# Почему проверка на то что строка является палиндромом работает только с латинскими буквами

Tags: java

Есть код для проверки на палиндром, но работает он только с латинскими буквами. Почему так?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    str = str.replaceAll("\\W", "");
    StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder(str);
    strbuild.reverse();
    String invstr = strbuild.toString();
    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(invstr))
        System.out.println(invstr);
    else {
        System.out.println("Строки не полиндромны");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Потому что все символы, не входящие в `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, вы заменяете на `""`. Поэтому слово "машина" легко и непринуждённо становится палиндромом, ибо пустая строка равна сама себе после переворачивания. 2. Слова "палиндромны" не существует, а уж тем более - "полиндромны". "палиндромность" туда же.

Comment: @Regent, почему не ответом? :-)

Comment: @Grundy я тогда торопился. Сейчас собрался было написать ответ, но напоролся на то, что `StringBuilder` не желает делать `reverse` для кириллицы. Как светлые мысли в голову придут - оформлю.

Comment: @Regent, а зачем reverse вообще? :-) циклы уже не котируются? :-)

Comment: @Grundy через цикл обязательно добавлю - в голову этот вариант пришел сразу) Как только пойму что и где сделал не так.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что все символы, не входящие в `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, вы заменяете на `""`. Поэтому слово "машина" легко и непринуждённо становится палиндромом, ибо пустая строка равна сама себе после переворачивания.

Самый простой вариант - не делать данную замену:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    String inversedStr = sb.reverse().toString();
    return inversedStr.equalsIgnoreCase(str);
}
```

И использование:

```
String str = "Тест";
if (isPalindrome(str))
    System.out.println("Палиндром");
else
    System.out.println("Не палиндром");
```

---

Вместо `StringBuilder` можно воспользоваться и обычным циклом:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str)
{
    String lowerCaseStr = str.toLowerCase();
    int length = lowerCaseStr.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        if (lowerCaseStr.charAt(i) != lowerCaseStr.charAt(length - i - 1))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

Если же обязательно нужно отфильтровывать неподходящие символы, то вместо `\W` можно воспользоваться перечислением допустимых символов:

```
String filteredStr = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z_0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]", "");
```

---

Отдельно стоит отметить, что если при использовании `Scanner`-а на любую строку из кириллицы код возвращает "Палиндром", то нужно задать кодировку, в которой `Scanner` будет считывать символы. У меня в консоли в NetBeans это, например, Windows-1251:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, "windows-1251");
```